# DB2 SQL - Filter non-xml, invalid xml data using XMLCAST(XMLQUERY (Xpath) function in case statement

Tags: sql, db2

Need help in filtering bad xml data from the column which is blob format. Using the below query to achieve this and facing the below error.

Query:
`SELECT  COLUMN1 AS NAME,  CASE WHEN COLUMN2 = '' THEN  XMLCAST( XMLQUERY( '$file/*:value' PASSING XMLPARSE( DOCUMENT TABLE."DATA" ) AS "file" ) AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE COLUMN2 END AS INFO FROM TABLE`

Error:
[Code: -16110, SQL State: 2200M]  XML syntax error. Expected to find "Comment or PI".. SQLCODE=-16110, SQLSTATE=2200M, DRIVER=4.22.29

Comment: What exactly is your question, and your Db2 version and platform? SQL16110N is indicating an XML error. The XML doc is not well-formed ("BAD XML").

Comment: @data_henrik: I'm trying to retrieve value from that xpath. Due bad xml in that column the query is failing to parse. So I want to skip them. DB2 version 11 and DBVisualizer is client tool I'm using

Comment: So you have to react to the error, to catch it. It is not done with a single query. What is the overall scenario?

Comment: The query is working if I run it for specific day because there aren't any bad xml format on that day. When I just run with date range it is failing with SQLCODE=-16110. So I have to exclude the bad xml's and only pull or parse right ones.

For example:
Good one: <value>Not Eligible</value>

Bad one: <value>Not Eligible</alue>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "safe" XMLPARSE function in Db2, but you may create it.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

-- Returns NULL on bad document
CREATE FUNCTION XMLPARSE_SAFE (P_DOC CLOB (1M))
RETURNS XML
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN END;
    RETURN XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT P_DOC);
END@

-- Usage
SELECT S, XMLPARSE_SAFE (S) AS DOC
FROM 
(
VALUES
  '<value>Not Eligible</value>'
, '<value>Not Eligible</alue>'
) T (S)@
```